# Why won't this NAT rule work?

Tags: windows, cisco, router, nat, rdp

I need to make a NAT rule to allow a user to access their workstation from networks outside of our own. I have added the following line to my router's configuration file (it's a Cisco 2911), which specifies the internal IP and port as well as the external IP and port that I'd like the system to be accessible at;

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.xxx.xxx.33 3389 204.xxx.xxx.26 55512 extendable
```

and have also specified to allow the external port through the ACL applied to the WAN interface;

```
permit tcp any any eq 55512
```

So why isn't this working? I can connect fine to the system inside the network, but not from the outside using the settings configured in the NAT rule shown above. Allowing all inbound connections through all firewall profiles on the host I am attempting to connect to makes no difference, neither allowing edge traversal for RDP protocols on the firewall. thanks for any possible assistance.

Comment: What is your Cisco IOS version? The rules have changed over the years.

Comment: @CoryKnutson 15.4 or 15.3, not sure which, but either of those two. Shouldn't be any difference there.

Comment: The ACL applied to the WAN is input or output?

Comment: @mikhailkhirgiy it's applied to the input.

Comment: Well. Try to connect from Internet and watch​ `router#sh ip nat trans | i 55512` on Cisco. Also see ACL rules on Cisco LAN interface and firewall rules on the server.

Comment: Can you post a full configuration?

Answer (score 0):

For your firewall rule, the destination port is not 55512. You should also always avoid `permit any any` rules. I believe you should have something similar to

```
permit tcp any 172.xxx.xxx.33 eq 3389
```